# Android ActionBar Tabs - Swipe

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

it would be nice, if i could swipe between the tabs i had in my actionbar.

I've followed these tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html but it wont work. :( I cannot swipe with a gesture between the tabs.

Here is my main activity:

```
public class Hauptmenue_extended extends ActionBarActivity implements
        android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hauptmenue_extended);

        try {           
            mPullToRefreshAttacher = PullToRefreshAttacher.get(this);

            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);    
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


            Tab tabB = actionBar.newTab();
            tabB.setText("Home");
            tabB.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_home);
            tabB.setTabListener(new TabListener<Startmenue_activity>(this,
                    "Start", Startmenue_activity.class, this.mViewPager));
            actionBar.addTab(tabB);

            Tab tabA = actionBar.newTab();
            tabA.setText("");
            tabA.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_nachrichten_sel);
            tabA.setTabListener(new TabListener<Nachrichten_activity>(this,
                    "Nachrichten", Nachrichten_activity.class, this.mViewPager));
            actionBar.addTab(tabA);

            Tab tabC = actionBar.newTab();
            tabC.setText("");
            tabC.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_favoriten);
            tabC.setTabListener(new TabListener<Favoriten_activity>(this,
                    "Favoriten", Favoriten_activity.class, this.mViewPager));
            actionBar.addTab(tabC);



            this.conEinst = new conEinstellungen(getBaseContext());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // HelperClassAlertDialog.zeigeInfoDialog(this, "Error...",
        }
    }

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int index) {

            switch (index) {
            case 0:
                // Top Rated fragment activity
                return new Startmenue_activity();
            case 1:
                // Games fragment activity
                return new Nachrichten_activity();
            case 2:
                // Movies fragment activity
                return new Favoriten_activity();
            }

            return null;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // get item count - equal to number of tabs
            return 3;
        }

    }
```

And this is the XML:

> ```
> <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/pager"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
>     <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
>         android:id="@+id/tabs"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="top" />
> </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
> ```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what "it won't work" means.

Comment: you can create a new project using the "Tabs+swipe" template and look at that code for reference.

Comment: Sorry. I did it. I cannot swipe between the tabs with a gesture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works perfectly, you will swipe between tabs:

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
    CollectionPagerAdapter mCollectionPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(
           getSupportFragmentManager());

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager
        .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override

            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

        });
    for (int i = 0; i < mCollectionPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
    .setText(mCollectionPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
    .setTabListener(this));
    }

    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int NUM_ITEMS = 3; // number of tabs

    public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

    }

    @Override

    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = new TabFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(TabFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;

}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

    return NUM_ITEMS;

}

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    String tabLabel = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label1);
            break;
        case 1:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label2);
            break;
        case 2:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label3);
            break;

    }

    return tabLabel;

    }
    }

     public static class TabFragment extends Fragment {
     public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);
    int tabLayout = 0;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab1;
            break;
        case 1:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab2;
            break;
        case 2:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab3;
            break;
    }

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);
    return rootView;

    }

   }

   }
```

`activity_main`:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

`tab1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:text="@string/body1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`tab2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/body2" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

`tab3.xml`:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/body3" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. No it works. I dont really know what i did, but it works. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever seen this [this one](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). It will help you for creating Tabs with ActionBar